# Scrollspy not working with AngularJs Single Page Application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-1.7

I know this might have been probably asked before but through out the net I didn't get a single proper working post to my problem. Hence thought of asking it myself.

Scrollspy concept is not working, when I am using the routing in AngularJs(1.7.2)
[example-2](http://52.10.15.196/scroll-demo2/index.html#!/)

And its working here without routing [example-1](http://52.10.15.196/scroll-demo1/index.html#!/)

Let me elaborate what i did and expected:
I have a single page application where there is a menu section and body section. 
when body section is scrolled in need menu item to be auto selected based on location.
in example 1: both menu and body are in same page and example is working. but
in example 2: when i load the content of body from another view then menu auto selection isn't working.

It will be great if any one of you could point me towards right direction in resolving this issue.

Comment: "when i load the content of body from another view then menu auto selection isn't working" -> you can select it manually in this event

Comment: sorry, i am new to angularjs.. Can you please elaborate?